# Installing PECL library on heroku

Tags: php, heroku, pecl

Can anyone suggest a way to install a custom [PECL](https://pecl.php.net/) library on Heroku instance?

I have tried to include it via `composer.json` file, but following error is produced:

```
- composer.json/composer.lock requires ext-yaml * -> no matching package found.
```

Comment: Well composer wants you to have the yaml php extension - why not install that first?

Comment: @vuryss Can you suggest the way it can be installed on Heroku?

Comment: Yea I guess it's harder than it initially appeared. May be it depends on the library, can you tell us which library you want to install?

Comment: This is a php-yaml package which another library depends on and available as extension for Heroku

Comment: May be just a suggestion... you can import the Symfony Yaml library, then define the functions provided by normal YAML PHP extension to be wrappers of the symfony library. Then install composer with `--ignore-platform-reqs`.
This is just a suggestion, as I'm not that familiar with heroku.

Comment: @vuryss I'm aware of that package, but the goal is to install it as a PECL library